# PostgreSQL: "index row requires 1460216 bytes, maximum size is 8191"

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to populate a table with the content of a list of dictionaries built in Python, which looks like:

`diclist = [{'accession':'value', 'species':'value', 'seq':'value', 'length': 'value'},
            {'accession':'value', 'species':'value', 'seq':'value', 'length': 'value'}, 
...]`

'seq' values are strings with sometimes > 300.000 characters...

However, my data include genetic sequences which are pretty long so when I try to load these data into the table, PostgreSQL claims the following:

> index row requires 1460216 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Is there a way to increase the row index maximum size?? Or is there a way to compress the space required by my data?

I know BioPython and BioSQL are made to handle genetic sequences, but they don't exactly match what I need...

This is the function I've built for the moment (*diclist* is the list of dictionaries):

```
def insert_biosequence(diclist):
try:
params = config()
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO biosequence(accession, species, seq, length) VALUES (%(accession)s, %(species)s, %(seq)s, %(length)s)""", diclist)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
  except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
print(error)
finally:
if conn is not None:
  conn.close()
```

My CREATE TABLE command is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE biosequence (
accession TEXT,
species TEXT,
seq TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
length INTEGER
```

);

I'm not using any INDEX commands, I think it's done by default by PostgreSQL... should I?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you also share a sample of your data and also the type of index you're using?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question including all indexes and the INSERT statements you are using. What does that data look like that you insert? Why are you indexing such a large text value? That is very rarely useful to begin with. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do not post code in comments.

Comment: You cannot index such a long value. Index part of it and use that part in your `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: I've updated the post with your questions! Thanks!

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro are you by chance using PostBIS? https://github.com/no0p/postbis

Comment: No, I haven't used it...yet! But it looks great for what I need, thank you very much!

Comment: @SoniaOlaecheaLázaro PostBIS seems to be still under "early stage of development", but I guess it at least gives you a good idea on how to proceed. The genetic sequence compression proposed by the authors can be imho slightly improved, but it already helps a lot! Suerte :-)

Comment: btw: here is a presentation on the topic: https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/1/1b/Postbis_pgcon_eu_2012.pdf

Comment: Great! Muchas gracias! ;) I'm working on it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Given that your data is structured, you probably want to create a schema that better suits your structure and then load it in that format rather than just raw source data, or at the very least load the raw data and then transform it into your structure format for easier searching.

Otherwise, you might be able to use full text search with GIN index or a GIN index with the pg_trgm operators.